# Shc encrypted shell script not executable

Tags: bash, encryption, portability

I created an encrypted shell script with the tool `shc`.
The script works just fine on my computer but when I transfer it to 
another one (solaris 10 to solaris 10) I get the following error:
`invalid argument`
It's not a permission problem and the encrypted script should be ok I guess it's a header/compiler problem.

The `shc` command used was`shc -rf <filename>` so the script should work on another computer!?

Comment: From what I understand the `shc` tool generates C code and then compiles it. Are the both Solaris 10 machines of the same CPU architecture/model and binary compatible? Are both systems up to date, libc-wise?

Comment: Building on Joakim's comment, what is the output of `file <filename>`?  Compare this to what `file` returns for other binaries on both systems.

Comment: I don't have a c compiler on the target machine - so the .sh.x script has to be compiled before it can be executed?

Comment: And for reference: http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/sources/shc.html

Answer (score 2):

According to [The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/) you need to use the -r option to relax security and -f to specify your script file:

```
shc -r -f script.sh
```

Comment: Still no use, it's not executing the complied file.